# No Spring Bean found in EJB with SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor

Tags: spring, ejb, autowired, interceptor

I need some help: I have one EAR-File, containing one WAR-File, one EJB-Jar-File and some "shared" libs:

```
aopalliance-1.0.jar commons-logging-1.1.1.jar log4j-1.2.16.jar spring-aop-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar spring-context-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar spring-context-support-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar spring-core-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar spring-expression-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
```

The War File has a Context initializer which find the spring config and loads everything well.
I now want to use another Spring Context for the EJB Jar.
My EJB is defined as

```
@Stateless(mappedName = "ejb/SpringRocks")
@RemoteHome(com.ibm.websphere.ola.ExecuteHome.class)
@Interceptors(SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor.class)
public class WolaUseCaseOne {
  @Autowired
  private DummyService dummyService;
  /* ...More stuff here */
```

Inside the EJB-JAR, there is also a beanRefContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
  <bean id="myEjb" name="myEjb" class="org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext">
   <constructor-arg value="classpath*:META-INF/spring/simpleEjb.xml" />
  </bean>
</beans>
```

The simpleEjb.xml is is also inside the EJB-Jar and is defining a very simple Bean:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
  <bean id="myDummyService" class="com.provinzial.beispielanwendung.batch.wola.DummyServiceImpl" />
</beans>
```

As described, the WEB Part works perfect, but when the EJB is called, the SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor is called, but seems to do nothing. What do I have to do, to get a Spring Context created?! My hope was that it is initialized when the EJB is created. I created a Subclass of SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor with some loggers, but the class is only created, no method is called !
What else do I have to do? Or does anybody have a valid EAR File example?
I think the Problem is that inside the EJB Module no context is initialized...

Greets
 Timo

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar issue with my EJB (no WAR).  This is what fixed mine,

1. I was missing the spring-aop jar on my classpath.  I see you have it so good there.
2. In my ejb-jar.xml file, I set the meta-data flag to true so I did not get prompted on deployment to complete.

I set to "false" for one deployment to see what IBM generated for me.  In the ejb-jar.xml it added the following (my MDB is named TaskMDB),

```
<assembly-descriptor>
        <interceptor-binding>
            <ejb-name>TaskMDB</ejb-name>
            <interceptor-class>org.springframework.ejb.interceptor.SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor</interceptor-class>
        </interceptor-binding>
    </assembly-descriptor>

    <interceptors>
        <interceptor>
            <interceptor-class>org.springframework.ejb.interceptor.SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor</interceptor-class>
            <post-activate>
                <lifecycle-callback-class>org.springframework.ejb.interceptor.SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor</lifecycle-callback-class>
                <lifecycle-callback-method>autowireBean</lifecycle-callback-method>
            </post-activate>
            <pre-passivate>
                <lifecycle-callback-class>org.springframework.ejb.interceptor.SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor</lifecycle-callback-class>
                <lifecycle-callback-method>releaseBean</lifecycle-callback-method>
            </pre-passivate>
            <post-construct>
                <lifecycle-callback-class>org.springframework.ejb.interceptor.SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor</lifecycle-callback-class>
                <lifecycle-callback-method>autowireBean</lifecycle-callback-method>
            </post-construct>
            <pre-destroy>
                <lifecycle-callback-class>org.springframework.ejb.interceptor.SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor</lifecycle-callback-class>
                <lifecycle-callback-method>releaseBean</lifecycle-callback-method>
            </pre-destroy>
        </interceptor>
    </interceptors>
```

Then I added what IBM generated (the assembly-descriptor and interceptors stanzas) back to my ejb-jar.xml and set the metadata-complete back to true.

Then it worked.  Hope this helps.

Here is the full ejb-jar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar version="3.1" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd">
    <display-name>ares-api-uow-ejb</display-name>
    <enterprise-beans>
        <message-driven id="TaskMDB">
            <ejb-name>TaskMDB</ejb-name>
            <ejb-class>something.api.uow.ejb.mdb.TaskMDB</ejb-class>
            <messaging-type>javax.jms.MessageListener</messaging-type>
            <transaction-type>Bean</transaction-type>
        </message-driven>
    </enterprise-beans>
</ejb-jar>
```

Comment: Hi Bulldogs, thanks for your reply... I do not use ejb-jar.xml at all, just plain annotaitons. Can you send me your complete ejb-jar.xml ?